# How to make a long div to automatically scroll until it reaches the bottom of the div?

Tags: javascript

I have a long div that I  would like to have automatically scrolling up until it reaches the bottom of the div. But in the meantime it can also be scrolled by the user.

Exactly like what they've done here:
http://sprawl.space/

They had something like this in the code:

```
var autoscroll;
var hash = window.location.hash;

if(!hash.match("shard")) {  
    startScroll();
  }

function startScroll(){
  autoscroll = setInterval(function(){
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 1);
  }, 100);
}
```

But I have no idea how it works with hash... Is there something similar that I could use to make my div auto scroll up(when I click a button)?

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor that code to this without using jQuery:

```
yourButton.addEventListener('click', e => {

    startScroll(yourDiv);

});

let startScroll = el => {

    let autoScroll = setInterval(() => {

        let divHeight = window.pageYOffset + el.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        let scrollPosition = window.innerHeight + window.scrollY;

        window.scrollY < divHeight + el.offsetHeight && scrollPosition < document.body.offsetHeight ? window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + 1) : clearInterval(autoScroll);

    }, 100);
}
```

This enables you to:

1. Start automatically scrolling your div when a button is clicked.
2. Continue the slow scroll even if a user scrolls.
3. Stop scrolling (and running the script) when the div/page is scrolled through.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much, this is exactly what I'd like to do. However I tried your code but it's not working. I created a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sytx99/bhvrp4wx/16/ I wonder what I'm missing here? In the demo I have a "gallery" button, and when I click it a purple div will appear and that's the div I want to use auto scroll for.

Comment: I had a look at your fiddle, and I saw that the code wasn't working. after console logging all the values, I've found why it's happening. It's because your document's body element is only 47 pixels tall, so the height of the body element used in the logic is always shorter than your DIV. I've edited your HTML, JS and CSS to adjust for this: https://jsfiddle.net/5L96y0dk/

Comment: @Coco Yuan any luck with the updated code reference in my comment?

Answer (score 0):

**Automatically scroll until reaches the bottom**

1. Will Automatically start when the page is loaded.(No need to click any button)
2. Will automatically stop when reaches the bottom of the page.

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html');
const maxScrollPosition = document.querySelector('html').offsetHeight - window.innerHeight;

let pos = window.scrollY;
let speed = 50; // Scorll Speed
let scrollGap = 5; // Scroll Gap

let scroll = (x) => window.scrollTo({
    top: x,
    behavior: 'smooth'
});

let timer = setInterval(() => {
    pos = pos + scrollGap;

    if (maxScrollPosition > pos) {
        scroll(pos);
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 100*(100/speed));

document.addEventListener('wheel', () => {
    wheelStartAndEnd();
});

let started;
let timeOut;

wheelStartAndEnd = () => {
    if (timeOut) {
        clearInterval(timeOut)
    } else if (!started) {
        started = true;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    timeOut = setInterval(() => {

        pos = window.scrollY;
        timer = setInterval(() => {
            pos = pos + scrollGap;

            if (maxScrollPosition > pos) {
                scroll(pos);
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, 100*(100/speed));

        clearInterval(timeOut);
        started = undefined;
        timeOut = undefined;
    }, 100);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Auto Scroll Down</title>
    <style>
        #x {
            height: 300vh;
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, coral 0%, cornflowerblue 100%);
        }
    </style>
    <script defer src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='x'>
    <button id='elem'>Click to scroll</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```